# Regarding Ubuntu12.04 instalation on Windows 7 64-bit OS

Tags: 12.04

When I try to install Ubuntu 12.04 by DVD, I insert the DVD and select the booting option as DVD. Next I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to install. After few second my screen goes blank like when the computer is turned off.

During this blank screen there are quiet sounds of disk writing for about 15 to 20 minutes  from the DVD writer, After this the sound stops, My computer is on but the screen remains blank.

please help me install Ubuntu on my system.

My system configuration is--

- Hp pavilion g4,
- RAM 4 GB,
- Hard disk 640 GB,
- Processor Intel i5,
- operating system is Windows 7 home basic 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from USB instead of CD-rom.

This is how to create a bootable usb:

### [Booting and installing from USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/319077/booting-and-installing-from-usb)

Note: To boot from USB, you need to tell your BIOS that you want to do that.
You can access your BIOS when pressing F10 while turning on the computer. Then search for boot options and select USB or 'flashdisk'.